# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

i've got this error in my console

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './components/tileHeader/controller.js' does not provide an export named 'tileHeader'

this is my code
**components/tileHeader/controller.js:**

```
Vue.component('tileHeader',{
    template: '#tileHeader',
    data(){
        return{
            count:0
        }
    },
})
```

**components/tileHeader/view.html:**

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="tileHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <!--<div v-show="item.label != null || item.label == undefined" 
                    class="label">{{item.label}}</div>
                    <img v-show="item.image != null" src="item.image"/>-->
                    <p>This is a Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>
```

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from './vue.js';
import { tileHeader } from './components/tileHeader/controller.js';

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'tileHeader': tileHeader
    },
  })
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Vue X-Templates</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="#app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i'm working with x-templates.
this is my project structure:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtCYo.png)

Comment: If you don't export `tileHeader` from controller.js, you can't import it

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this ?

Create a single file that will contain your html / css and js.

**tileHeader.vue :**

```
<template>
<!-- Your view.html  -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'tileHeader',
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Since the file has a export default, you'll be able to import it in another file

Add to **main.js :**

```
import tileHeader from "./components/tileHeader.vue";
```